# MYSQL JOINs & COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, join, count

Have 3 Tables... Need to select users that haven't booked a lesson for the next week, and send an email.

Think I'm looking at

```
WHERE `LESSONS`.`DATE` > CURDATE()  
  AND `LESSONS`.`DATE` <= (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

That works to select the range of dates... However I'm then having a problem joining that to the bookings to see if they have booked, and if they HAVEN'T then I need to grab their email address... I'd rather not use PHP to loop through and query data. I obviously just want to run the single query.

As you can probably tell I'm not in the know when it comes to MYSQL.

Help appreciated. Thanks.

```
USERS
-----------
ID | EMAIL, ETC


LESSONS
-----------
ID | DATE, ETC


BOOKINGS
-----------
ID | LESSON_ID | USER_ID, ETC
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
SELECT  u.*
FROM    USERS u LEFT JOIN
    Bookings b  ON  u.ID = b.USER_ID LEFT JOIN
    LESSONS l   ON  b.LESSON_ID = l.ID
            AND l.DATE > CURDATE() AND l.DATE <= (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY)
WHERE   l.ID IS NULL
```

This should get all users that do not have any bookings for lessons for next week.

Have a look at [Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

This is a nive visual representation of joins.

Answer (score 0):

use `in` or `exists`?

```
SELECT users.* FROM users
WHERE users.id NOT IN
(SELECT Bookings.user_id FROM Bookings JOIN Lessons ON Bookings.lesson_id = lessons.id
WHERE lessons.date > CURDATE() AND lessons.date <= (CURDATE()+INTERVAL7 7 DAY)
```

There may be syntactical differences in MySQL opposed to SQL server, that I'm more familiar with.